# Can't get a number guessing game to work in C

Tags: c

Tried to write a program in C to say the amount of times you guessed the right number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, searchNumber, Number, rightGuess;
    rightGuess = 0;
    printf("Give your number: ");
    scanf("%d",&searchNumber);
    printf("\n\n Give 10 numbers: ");
    for(i=1;i<=9;i++){
        scanf("%d \n",&Number);
        if(Number == searchNumber){
            rightGuess++;
        }
    }

    printf("You guessed the number %d times",&rightGuess);
    return 0;
}
```

However every time I run it, it says I guessed the number 6356736 times. Even though I only entered a number 0 times. Any help?

Comment: what do you think &rightGuess means in your printf?

Comment: Nice one UKMonkey.

Comment: Upvoted, this approaches perfection 1) example code, 2) expected output, 3) actual output 4) well-written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `printf` ought to be

`printf("You guessed the number %d times", rightGuess);`

i.e. *don't* pass a *pointer* to `rightGuess` in correspondence to the `%d` format specifier. Currently the program behaviour is undefined! (It could well be outputting the address of `rightGuess` which accounts for the large number - but don't ever rely on that; you need to use `%p` to output pointer addresses.)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you made a mistake in `printf()`.

If there is a variable named `var`, `&var` means the memory address where variable `var` is. Maybe the number `6356736` you saw in your program is the memory address, not the value in variable var.

You will have to change this line in order to print the value of variable `rightGuess`

```
printf("You guessed the number %d times", &rightGuess);
```

To this line.

```
printf("You guessed the number %d times", rightGuess);
```

Comment: "So the number 6356736 you saw in your program is the memory address". It *probably* is but might not be. I wouldn't assert that if I were you: the program behaviour is actually undefined.